# Strange installation of XETEX

Tags: installing

I use an Ubuntu OS and install `texlive` from the TUG DVD. I tried to run `xetex` and was told that it was not available and to get it I had to do something like `sudo apt-get install xetex` which I did but it still didn't work complaining that for the particular document it couldn't find `mathtools.sty`. It was suggested that I had two versions of `xetex`, one an Ubuntu delivered version and another from the DVD. I couldn't deleted the Ubuntu version but did delete the DVD texlive version but it still didn't work.

I did a search of my computer for `xetex` and `pdflatex` with the following result.

```
peter@ubuntu:/usr$ find -name xetex
./share/texmf-texlive/tex/xetex
./share/texmf-texlive/fonts/misc/xetex
./share/texmf-texlive/scripts/xetex
./share/doc/texlive-xetex/xetex
./share/doc/texlive-doc/xetex
./bin/xetex
./local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/xetex
./local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/misc/xetex
./local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/xetex
./local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/web2c/xetex
./local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/xetex
./local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/misc/xetex
./local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/doc/xetex
./local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/web2c/xetex
peter@ubuntu:/usr$ find -name pdflatex
./bin/pdflatex
./local/texlive/2020/bin/i386-linux/pdflatex
./local/texlive/2019/bin/i386-linux/pdflatex
```

I checked my `path` and the `texlive` installation was at the head of the path s there was no reason for the Ubuntu `xetex` version to be used.

```
bash: /usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/i386-linux:/home/peter/bin:
      /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin: 
      /usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games: No such file or directory
```

I am now very confused as to what I ought to do. My inclination is to delete the `xetex` (and `xelatex`) files from the `/usr/share` and `/usr/bin` directories and use `tlmgr` to get the `texlive` `xetex` and `xelatex` programs.

Comment: When I had problems using TeX Live from the DVD or from an Internet installation, my solution was to use TeX Live manager GUI (`sudo tlmgr gui`, requires Perl and Perltk if I remember well) to update symlinks. In any case, it's better to remove any conflicting installation from Ubuntu.

Comment: @JairoA.delRio I usually recommend doing **nothing** with symlinks, especially on Debian based systems, which possibly have their TeX Live installation. Having `/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/i386-linux` first in the PATH variable is sufficient. What can happen is that an update with `apt` forces updating of the Debian TeX Live, with consequent substitution of the symlinks; chaos ensues.